# Set socket.io emit value from cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I'm trying to make a sort of a chatroom site, now when you load the site you get this input field asking for you to input a name like this: [image]
after you enter the name and press the button next to it which says "move on to the chat", it sets the username using this:

```
function setUsername() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("name");
    var txtboxval = textbox.value;
    if(textbox.value.length <= 20 && textbox.value.length >= 4){
      socket.emit('setUsername', document.getElementById('name').value);
      setCookie("username", txtboxval, 30);
      socket.on('userExists', function(data) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = data;
      });
    }
    else{
        alert("Nimen on oltava vähintään 4 kirjainta pitkä");
        return false;
      }
    };
```

it sets the name to be whatever you input as long as it fits the requirements and will show it in the messages you send, it will also set the value into cookies.

on the next page it will show messages as such: [image]

now this still works as supposed to, next when I reload the page it will show a popup cause the cookies are set [image]

the issue comes after this part, it will go forward to the message sending page with this function:

```
function checkCookie() {
      var user = getCookie("username");
      if (user != "") {
          alert("Welcome again " + user);
          setUsername2();
          document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="messagebox"><input type = "text" id = "message" placeholder = "Kirjoita viestisi tähän">\
          <button type = "button" id="sending" name = "button" onclick = "sendMessage()">Send</button></div>\
          <div id = "message-container"></div></div>';
      }
    }
```

the setUsername2 function:

```
  function setUsername2() {
    socket.emit('setUsername', user);
  }
```

after this it should load and show the same name as mentioned in the cookie message but it will only return "[object Object]" as the name:[image]

and will only show as {} in the console[image]

What's going wrong here, is there a supposed reason to why the user won't get set again from cookies properly?

Please do ask if something is unclear I'll try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: I am not sure why you are seeing the [object Object] yet, but when you reload the page, are you still listening for this event ```socket.on('userExists', function(data)...``` after reload? The listener for it only appears to be in setUsername().

That event is called after you emit ```socket.emit('setUsername', user);``` but you do not set the socket.on event for that in setUsername2().

Comment: @JamesPooley I have partially figured out the problem, it was displaying the name as object Object cause I thought that it would be inside the scope of the other function it was called inside of, but turns out I had to define another variable inside `setUsername2()` function like this: `var name = getCookie('username');` and `socket.emit('setUsername', name);` instead, otherwise the variable would just be empty, I also had to remove a duplicate checker so it can pass through, now the only issue I have is that I must somehow make the duplicate checker work on normal entry but not on cookies.